# How to deserialize List<String> as comma separated String in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize the below JSON in `Map<String,String>` format, but with the `codes` param in List format. I needs to deserialize `codes` as a comma-separated string in a map value.

```json
{
  "frequency": "Daily",
  "level": "Standard",
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "test user",
  "codes": [
    "177",
    "989"
  ]
}
```

I tried to change to a `Map<String,Object>` and was able to deserialize it. But I want to add a custom deserializer for it. Is any way to add a custom deserializer for it?

Comment: Have you looked up "Jackson custom deserializer"? There should be a lot of results for that.

Answer (score -1):

If it were me I would create a POJO class to map the JSON response to the object. I would just use this: https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create the classes I need and then do:

```
Example object = new Gson().fromJson(json, Example.class);
```

Using the above link will save time and prevent the headache of mapping the JSON object. You could then refer in your code like:

```
List<String> codeList =  object.getCodes();
```